# What is the difference between Pattern Matching and Guards?

Tags: haskell, syntax, guard

I am very new to Haskell and to functional programming in general. My question is pretty basic. What is the difference between Pattern Matching and Guards?

**Function using pattern matching**

```
check :: [a] -> String
check [] = "Empty"
check (x:xs) = "Contains Elements"
```

**Function using guards**

```
check_ :: [a] -> String
check_ lst
    | length lst < 1 = "Empty"
    | otherwise = "Contains elements"
```

To me it looks like Pattern Matching and Guards are fundamentally the same. Both evaluate a condition, and if true will execute the expression hooked to it. Am I correct in my understanding?

In this example I can either use pattern matching or guards to arrive at the same result. But something tells me I am missing out on something important here. Can we always replace one with the other?

Could someone give examples where pattern matching is preferred over guards and vice versa?

Comment: It doesn't related directly to your question, but the first version of the function is probably better because it is more efficient and will work for infinite lists.

Comment: Pattern matching is about the *form* of data, guards about the *contents*.

Comment: Check the [definition of pattern matching](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#pattern-matching) in the Haskell Language Report.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Actually, they're fundamentally quite different! At least in Haskell, at any rate.

Guards are both simpler and more flexible: They're essentially just special syntax that translates to a series of if/then expressions. You can put arbitrary boolean expressions in the guards, but they don't do anything you couldn't do with a regular `if`.

Pattern matches do several additional things: They're the **only way to deconstruct data**, and they **bind identifiers within their scope**. In the same sense that guards are equivalent to `if` expressions, pattern matching is equivalent to `case` expressions. Declarations (either at the top level, or in something like a `let` expression) are also a form of pattern match, with "normal" definitions being matches with the trivial pattern, a single identifier.

Pattern matches also tend to be the main way stuff actually happens in Haskell--attempting to deconstruct data in a pattern is one of the few things that forces evaluation.

By the way, you can actually do pattern matching in top-level declarations:

```
square = (^2)

(one:four:nine:_) = map square [1..]
```

This is occasionally useful for a group of related definitions.

GHC also [provides the ViewPatterns extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns) which sort of combines both; you can use arbitrary functions in a binding context and then pattern match on the result. This is still just syntactic sugar for the usual stuff, of course.

---

As for the day-to-day issue of which to use where, here's some rough guides:

- Definitely use pattern matching for anything that can be matched directly one or two constructors deep, where you don't really care about the compound data as a whole, but do care about most of the structure. The `@` syntax lets you bind the overall structure to a variable while also pattern matching on it, but doing too much of that in one pattern can get ugly and unreadable quickly.
- Definitely use guards when you need to make a choice based on some property that doesn't correspond neatly to a pattern, e.g. comparing two `Int` values to see which is larger.
- If you need only a couple pieces of data from deep inside a large structure, particularly if you also need to use the structure as a whole, guards and accessor functions are usually more readable than some monstrous pattern full of `@` and `_`.
- If you need to do the same thing for values represented by different patterns, but with a convenient predicate to classify them, using a single generic pattern with a guard is usually more readable. Note that if a set of guards is non-exhaustive, anything that fails all the guards will drop down to the next pattern (if any). So you can combine a general pattern with some filter to catch exceptional cases, then do pattern matching on everything else to get details you care about.
- Definitely don't use guards for things that could be trivially checked with a pattern. Checking for empty lists is the classic example, use a pattern match for that.
- In general, when in doubt, just stick with pattern matching by default, it's usually nicer. If a pattern starts getting really ugly or convoluted, then stop to consider how else you could write it. Besides using guards, other options include extracting subexpressions as separate functions or putting `case` expressions inside the function body in order to push some of the pattern matching down onto them and out of the main definition.

Comment: Don't forget about their baby, pattern guards!

Comment: @luqui: Ah, yes! An embarrassing oversight on my part; thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 11):

For one, you can put boolean expressions within a guard.

[For example](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-guards):

> Just as with list comprehensions, boolean expressions can be freely mixed with among the pattern guards. For example:
>
> ```
> f x | [y] <- x
>     , y > 3
>     , Just z <- h y
>     = ...
> ```

---

**Update**

There is a nice quote from [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) about the difference:

> Whereas patterns are a way of making sure a value conforms to some form and deconstructing it, guards are a way of testing whether some property of a value (or several of them) are true or false. That sounds a lot like an if statement and it's very similar. The thing is that guards are a lot more readable when you have several conditions and they play really nicely with patterns.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is *not* standard Haskell, but is a GHC extension.

Comment: On the other hand, purely-syntactic extensions in by far the most popular compiler are pretty safe to use. Worst-case scenario is you have to manually desugar it later for the sake of porting to some other compiler.

Comment: @Antal, actually it is standard Haskell 2010.  http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13

Answer (score 10):

> To me it looks like Pattern Matching and Guards are fundamentally the same. Both evaluate a condition, and if true will execute the expression hooked to it. Am I correct in my understanding?

Not quite. First pattern matching can not evaluate arbitrary conditions. It can only check whether a value was created using a given constructor.

Second pattern matching can bind variables. So while the pattern `[]` might be equivalent to the guard `null lst` (not using length because that'd not be equivalent - more on that later), the pattern `x:xs` most certainly is not equivalent to the guard `not (null lst)` because the pattern binds the variables `x` and `xs`, which the guard does not.

A note on using `length`: Using `length` to check whether a list is empty is very bad practice, because, to calculate the length it needs to go through the whole list, which will take `O(n)` time, while just checking whether the list is empty takes `O(1)` time with `null` or pattern matching. Further using `length´ just plain does not work on infinite lists.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other good answers, I'll try to be specific about guards: Guards are just syntactic sugar. If you think about it, you will often have the following structure in your programs:

```
f y = ...
f x =
  if p(x) then A else B
```

That is, if a pattern matches, it is followed right after by a if-then-else discrimination. A guard folds this discrimination into the pattern match directly:

```
f y = ...
f x | p(x) = A
    | otherwise = B
```

(`otherwise` is defined to be `True` in the standard library). It is more convenient than an if-then-else chain and sometimes it also makes the code much simpler variant-wise so it is easier to write than the if-then-else construction.

In other words, it is sugar on top of another construction in a way which greatly simplifies your code in many cases. You will find that it eliminates a lot of if-then-else chains and make your code more readable.

Comment: I would write `p x` rather then `p(x)`.